# uninstall windows 10 defender update

Tags: windows-defender

I need to uninstall the latest windows 10 defender update. However, these updates are not found in the 'uninstall an update'screen you can find under the update panel.

When I go to 'security at a glance'I only have the option to scan for new updates, not to remove old ones.

Can I remove the latest update? And how?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Microsoft forum:](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/all/windows-defender-definition-updates/b22e3d11-c31f-41f3-8657-3490e9a2bf84)

> Click "View Installed Updates" in the "Programs and Features" section. Locate the Windows Defender update that you want to remove from the list of installed updates. Click the Windows Defender update to highlight and select it. Click "Uninstall."

Comment: This does not work sadly. There is only one update left, and I think it is the one. But I can not right click it. Or I can, but it shows no context menu and no option to uninstall.